# Can I debug a python package after installing it?

Tags: python, module, pytorch

I'm interested in a package and wanted to play around with the code: https://github.com/aiqm/torchani

The package itself is not complex and the key modules are included in the `torchani` folder. I wanted to use the VSCode debugger to do some experiments with the components and track the code. Do I need to run `python setup.py --install`, or I should simply go to the folder and run the modules without installing?

The problem is: there will be a lot of relative import issues if I directly run the code in the parent folder. If I install the package, then the code will probably be compiled and my changes will not be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the package with `python setup.py install` (or `pip install [-e] .`).

For the debugging part you can use the debugger of VSCode, just set `justMyCode: False` in the `launch.json`.